# Divide all values but one in sql table

Tags: sql

i got this table, and i want to divide all the values on one of the columns except one.

I havent wrote any code about it just looking for an explanation on how to do it, if anyone could help out would appreciate.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: You can mention 1 where clause to avoid that cond.

Comment: Please provide your table so that it will be easy to understand your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to modify the content of one column in all rows except one, you can use the following query:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columName = columnName / 42 WHERE rowId !=42;
```

`WHERE` contains the condition that has to evaluate to true, in order for the update to take effect. My example modifies all rows except for those whose `rowId` column contains the value `42`.

Comment: Thank you it does the job as i wanted it too +1, thank you.